# logging in + database issue

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Every time I log in, the password is erased from the database. The rest of the data is intact. I am a beginner in web programming and I have no clue about this. What could be the possible reason for this?

[code copied from the comment]

```
$user= $_POST['username']; 
$pass = $_POST['password']; 
if((isset($user))&&(isset($pass))) { 
  $query ="Select password from table1 where user_name='".$user."'"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(); 
  $r= mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(); 

  if(!strcmp($pass, $r)) { 
   echo "succesful"; 
   session_start(); 
   $_SESSION['username']=$user; 
   $_SESSION['logged']=1; 
   header("Refresh: 0; URL = ..\home\index.php"); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Login means? into your Application or Database Interface like MySQL??.. Are you just using 'SELECT' query for login or something else??..

Comment: Well, i wrote a login code where, using the select query, i take the password from the table corresponding to the username entered. If the password from the table and the password matches, the login is successful. This is basically the summary of the login code.

Comment: Need the code to find out whats the exact problem?

Comment: SELECTs don't "erase" anything; until you write the code you're using the question cannot be answered unless someone does a mind-reading miraculous guess

Comment: Update your answer by editing it, don't write code in comments

Comment: Are you sure you don't experience a $_SESSION loss instead? you're echoing something before starting sessions and issuing a redirect, and that should give you an error

Comment: that is the part of the code in question, I guess..

Comment: thats not.. it just shows momentarily and then redirects to the index.php page.. it's not important. I could erase that.

Comment: You need do `session_start` at first line, when check isset($_POST['username']) ->> session_start(); $user= isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : false; 
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : false; 
if($user !== false && $password !== false) {

Comment: $query returns the password. It works alright when one logs in for the first time. After that, the password gets erased from the database and one cant login after that.

Comment: Can you start the session before checking if the user has entered the right password? Would that be safe??

Comment: There's no code there that deletes somethng from database; I think you mean the $_SESSION gets lost, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need do `session_start` at first line, when check isset($_POST['username'])

```
session_start(); 
$user= isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : false; 
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : false; 

if($user !== false && $password !== false) {
```

when you do this correct:

```
$r= mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(); 
if(!strcmp($pass, $r['password'])) {
```

and header:

```
header("Location: ..\home\index.php");
```

Comment: This code is much cleaner thanks! But the problem is still there.. :\

Comment: @Android : There's no code there that deletes somethng from database; I think you mean the $_SESSION gets lost, maybe?

Comment: @Android, and how you check is user authorized?

Comment: @Android, I mean, after logging, how you check auth user? if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) ?

Comment: yeah.. once the user logs in $_SESSION['logged'] is set as 1. Thats what I am using..